# I can't get Path to recoginize Java SDK

Tags: java, path, cmd.exe

Alright, I'm trying to access Java SDK tools such as JavaC through CMD but I can't.

Here is my echo %path%
C:\Users\msivri>echo %PATH%

> C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\Wind
>   owsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI
>   Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static; c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\; c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Mic rosoft
>   SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\10 0\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform
>   Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web
>   Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows K its\8.0\Windows
>   Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\T
>   ools\Binn\;

Here is what my PATH system variable contains:

> C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform
>   Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web
>   Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows
>   Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\110\Tools\Binn\;

Notice that they are both different for some reason...

Comment: Did you modify your PATH via the Windows UI?  If so, only cmd prompts opened after you modified it will have the changes . . . note that it's also a good idea to put more specific paths at the end, rather than the beginning as PATH will be searched in order . . .

Comment: Yup, that's right. Thanks, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you modified the system variable via Windows, and already had a command prompt open.

Note that changes you make to the system/environment variables will not be applied to already open cmd.exe prompts, but will be applied to all new instances.

As an aside, it's also a good idea to put more specific paths at the end, rather than the beginning of PATH, when you type a command at the prompt, the search order is first check the current working directory, then each of the items in path in order.  So with the paths as shown above, if you type "notepad.exe", it'll first check your current working directory, then the Java bin directory, then finally your C:\Windows\System32 directory.  So, in general, each command you type now will be just a little bit slower as it'll check the Java bin dir first for the command . . .